# Designing a 'new post' android activity

Tags: android

I am working on a social app that takes in text posts from users. Now I want to design an activity that takes input from the user for a new post. I want it to look like the 'create a new post' dialogs in popular apps like google +, Tumblr or facebook android apps. I tried searching the web for the like but couldn't find any. Kindly direct me to some good resource. Any good github project will be really helpful. [image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a custom dialog?

Comment: Am new to android. Not sure of the terms yet. That was what stopped me from searching for what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things.

1. Use a `DialogFragment`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) is the documentation and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) is an example and some information.
2. Hide a `View` that is on top of the layout with a semi transparent background and some padding causing it to look like your picture.

I hope this is enought to push you in the right direction. If you need extra information comment on this answer and I'll help you with it.

Comment: DialogFragment is a best choice for your social app View implementation...
sample example : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: @issamux Same link is in my answer ;)

Comment: @issamux doesn't matter, you provide extra information ;-)